# SAS insert to ARRAY only (example) first row from dataset

Tags: arrays, sas

I have bit a problem. I need insert to Array only (example) first array, best field by field.
How Can I do it? I will be grateful if also you point how insert column by column (I will be able to load chosen columns in the future).

```
data have;
infile DATALINES dsd missover;
input varr1 varr2 varr3;
CARDS;
1, 2, 3
2, 3, 4 
5, 4
4, 3
9, 4, 1
6,
;run;

data want;
   set have;
    array L[3] _temporary_ ;

if _n_ = 1 then 
    do;
        do i = 1 to 3;
            %LET j = i;
            L[i] = varr&i;  /*in this place I have problem*/
            put L[i];
        end;
    end;
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need macro, and not sure why you need temporary array `L`.

The array statement can be used to organize variables so they can be accessed in an array manner.  Loop over the variable array in order to copy the values into the temporary array.

The elements of a temporary array are not available for output, and **not** part of normal implicit program data vector (PDV) behaviors that would reset variables to missing.

```
data want;
  set have;
  array V varr1-varr3;
  array L[3] _temporary_;

  * save first rows values in temporary array for use in other rows;
  if _n_ = 1 then 
    do index = 1 to dim(V);
      L[index] = V[index];
    end;

  * … for example … ;

  array delta_from_1st [3];  * array statement implicitly creates three new variables that become part of PDV and get output;
  do index = 1 to dim(V);
    delta_from_1st[index] = V[index] - L[index];
  end;      
run;
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you, and I have one additionaly question - how put column name in fragment:
`delta_from_1st[index] = V[index] - L[index]`
I tried use `vname` but doesn't work.
I need example delta_[column name that calculated]
Thanks!

Comment: The data step can not dynamically create the variable names of it's output.  You can define the `delta` array as a grouping a data step variables (that would be added to the PDV).    `array delta delta_var1-deltavar3;`  The array construct in the example creates new variables based on the array name.  SAS can not process accessors of the form `array[<char-value>]`, you would have to use `HASH` object for that.  Finally, sometimes it is far easier to use a reporting procedure to get a look at data in a special way, instead of manually reorganizing the data into a new layout

Comment: Richard, thank for explanation. 
I see more and more often that SAS has a lot limitations.