# macro variable as numeric inside data step

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am asking for a little help.
[link where is question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55302251/sas-insert-to-array-only-example-first-row-from-dataset) 
In above post I have little problem set dynamic variable which I will count used columns. How I can do it?

```
data want;
  set have;
  array V varr1-varr3;
 call SYMPUTN('countxxx',dim(V)) /* here I try set numeric*/
  array L[&countxxx.] _temporary_;/* here input numeric*/

  * save first rows values in temporary array for use in other rows;
  if _n_ = 1 then 
    do index = 1 to dim(V);
      L[index] = V[index];
    end;

  * … for example … ;

  array delta_from_1st [&countxxx.];  * array statement implicitly creates three new variables that become part of PDV and get output;
  do index = 1 to dim(V);
    delta_from_1st[index] = V[index] - L[index];
  end;      
run;
```

Comment: If you want to explain what you're trying to do there may be other options, such as short cut lists and using an asterisk instead of an array with a fixed dimension.

Comment: Hey Reeza. Idea with asterisk is intresting but when I set asterisk didn't work. I have log `The array delta_from_1st has been defined with zero elements.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a character vs numeric issue.  All macro variables are character, but since your value is all digits the SAS compiler will interpret the text it generates as a number since you are not enclosing it in quotes.

The real issue is that you are trying to reference the macro variable COUNTXXX before you have created it.  The macro references are resolved before the data step starts running.  Split your step into two steps.

```
data _null_;
  set have;
  array V varr:;
  call SYMPUTX('countxxx',dim(V)) ;
  stop;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  array L[&countxxx.] _temporary_;
...
```

Comment: Hey Tom. Big thx for this solution. I thought that I can create and used variable inside data step between iterations, I do not like to share code to more steps than than need.